# Uglifyjs changes Angular scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twig, gulp, uglifyjs

To compress **js** files via **gulp** I have tried using both gulp modules

- [gulp-uglifyjs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-uglifyjs)
- [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-uglify)

but it changes the variable I define.

for eg:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[').endSymbol(']}');
    });
```

is compressed to:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[])
    .config(function(n){n.startSymbol("{[").endSymbol("]}")});
```

while using **Angularjs** with **Twig** I have to change the ***mustaches*** `{{ }}` to `{[ ]}` and the angularjs doesn't recognize the `n` instead of `$interpolateProvider`.

Any suggestions how to tell **uglifyjs** not to change my variables while compression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is when you need to include [ng-min](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ngmin) task into your build as well as it will protect your angular from minification problems.

Or by hand, but thats just silly...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[').endSymbol(']}');
    }
]);
```

Some docs on [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) minification issues scroll down to 'A Note on Minification.'